# When Shoud i override other function of Exception in Java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to define custom exceptions in java for android. Initially i thought of using enumerated exceptions, but after reading [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bakksjo/archive/2005/09/java_exception.html) link, i understood the disadvantages of using enumerated exception.

Having considered above i wrote a simple Custom Exception class :

```
public class EXInvalidEmployeeIDException extends Exception {
    public String msg;
    public Integer employeeID;

    public EXInvalidEmployeeIDException(Integer devID) {
        this.devID = devID;
    }

    public EXInvalidEmployeeIDException(Integer devID, string msg) {
        this.devID = devID;
        this.msg = msg;

    }

    public Integer getEmployeeID () {
        return this.devID;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID () {
        return this.msg
    }
}
```

**MY Question:**

1) Should i have to invoke super class constructors? In my code, i have not invoked any super class function, which still works fine.

2) If needed, what are the functions i need to override from super class (ie; Exception class)

In [this](http://java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/) link,  below methods are overriden

```
  A) Constructor,

  B) Constructor with String

  C) Constructor with Thowable.
```

3) Is my sample code suffice ?

Please Advise.

Comment: You may want to invoke the super constructor that specifies the error message. If you do take a `Throwable cause` then you want to pass that along as well. But it's optional. I don't think you need to override any methods.

Comment: Btw, you are not overriding methods here. You are providing constructors. Which constructors you need depends on what your application needs (when throwing your exception).

Comment: Thilo, Thanks for comment. So, which means, the sample exception which i wrote is suffice right ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating constructor methods for your own exceptions, then I think it is good (*and cheaper*)  to call `super();`. This way you ensure that `Throwable` (*Super class of `Exception`) initializes internal state variables as `detailMessage`, `cause` and so on.

You can review `Throwable` source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Throwable.java/) and see what I am telling you.

To answer your second question, you have to overwrite those constructors/methods that you want to customize, but don't forget to call super constructors/method once you have done your special work.

Finally I don't duplicate `msg` because if you call super, you are using `Throwable.detailMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

> Should i have to invoke super class constructors?

Always, but when the parent class has an accesible default constructor the compiler can supply it for you.

> If needed, what are the functions i need to override from super class (ie; Exception class)

The functionns you need to override, if any, depend entirely on what you need. What that means is up to you. Nobody can define it for you.